# numpy genfromtxt collapse recarray when data file has only one row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using genfromtxt function to read data from a csv file.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype=np.dtype(input_vars), delimiter=",")
```

Then I can access the array columns with e.g.:

```
data["My column name"]
```

which then returns a 1-dimensional vector. Only when the source file has exactly one data row, the array is collapsed - its `shape==()` and therefore the vector returned by `data["My column name"]` is not a vector but just a value and some subsequent functions fail because they expect a vector.

What I need is to make it always a vector. In other words, I need that genfromtxt does not collapse the dimensionality of the array even if the data file has only one row.

In other words, if the source data file has two rows, the `data.shape==(2,)`. But if the source data file has only one row, the `data.shape==()` but I need it to be `(1,)`. Then, if I am correct, `data["My column name"]` would return a vector (though with one element) and the subsequent functions would not fail.

How to do it? `data.reshape((1,))` and `np.atleast_1d(data)` do not work for me for some strange reason, not sure why...

Update:

I made a simple example to illustarate my problem.

Suppose I have two files:

mydata1.csv which is one row:

```
1,2,3
```

and mydata2.csv which has two rows:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

This is the code snippet (problem described in the comments):

```
import numpy as np
dt = [("A", "<i4"), ("B", "<i4"), ("C", "<i4")]
data2 = np.genfromtxt("mydata2.csv", dtype=dt, delimiter=",")
print(data2.shape)  # returns (2,)
data1 = np.genfromtxt("mydata1.csv", dtype=dt, delimiter=",")
print(data1.shape)  # returns () but I need it to return (1,)

data2["A"]  # returns a 1D vector with two values
data1["A"]  # returns a value (zero dimensional) bt I need a 1D vector with one value
```

All workarounds that I can come up with are a way too ugly and result in too much code refactoring. Ideally I would need to have always a 1-D recarray as the result of `genfromtxt`.

Comment: "data.reshape((1,)) and np.atleast_1d(data) do not work for me..."  Please be more specific.  What doesn't work?  Show an example, including what you actually got and what you expected.

Comment: I added a minimal example to reproduce what I was describing.

Comment: Thanks.  Now what doesn't work if you say `data1 = np.atleast_1d(data1)`?

Comment: OMG, I am so stupid! You are right. I forgot the assignment and wrote just np.atleast_1d(data1). This renders my question so retarded that I should delete it.

Comment: No worries.  I created an enhancement request to add the `ndmin` argument to genfromtxt: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4811

Comment: In other words, this is a reasonable question, even though you might not have asked it if you hadn't made a small mistake in your work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have only one line in the `csv` file you are obtaining `data` as a `np.void` object. You can use force `data` to be a `np.ndarray` doing:

```
data = np.atleast_1d(data)
```

Comment: As I wrote above, I forgot to write the assignment, I just wrote np.atleast_1d(data1). I thought that atleast_1d manipulates the source array in place. I am stupid. :(

Comment: @V.K. this kind of mistake is normal :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `genfromtxt`, you could try [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), with the argument `ndmin=1`.  (Of course, this won't be an option if you are using some of the enhanced features of `genfromtxt`.)

Comment: I am using genfromtxt because I need some of its features.